# Creating a new database with php/PDO using a variable as the database name

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$db_name = 'myDbName';
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `$db_name` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

The moment these 2 instructions are executed, the database is created, but its name is 'myDbName', quotes included.
If i remove the quotes in the first line, i'll get a PHP error, and  if i remove the  from the second one, i'll get a mySql error.
Is there a way to remove them/create a database with the correct name without directly accessing the DBMS?
I'd really prefer not to hardcode the name in the second line

Thanks in advance for the answers

Comment: Just to make sure, how do you know the name is `'myDbName'` with the quotes?

Comment: Try echoing the query before running it. Check the page's source to see what's outputted too.

Comment: @FirstOne, i checked it from the DBMS.<br>But i don't want the end user to have to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string concat and remove backticks

```
"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS  " . $db_name . " DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
```

you can also avoid  concat and using var inside quote (this could be useful if you need backticks for allow reserved word)

```
"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS  '$db_name' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
```

Comment: I'm not the op, but backticks are not related to interpolation, it's a mysql thing. If the idea is to just remove the backticks, it should also work using double quotes and simply using the var without concatenation.

Comment: Since it looks like the op wants to dynamically create databases, some names might need backticks. Take a look at the first example from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11321523/4577762)

Comment: @FirstOne  The OP in this question don't want the backtikcs   .. this is a simple solution ..there are many others .. solution .. you can post  your if you like ..

Comment: They didn't say the name is getting backticks, it's getting quotes. Don't worry, I'm just pointing to a possible problem that could happen for not using backticks, specially since they _prefer not to hardcode the name_ (they might use a reserved word as db name)

Comment: @FirstOne  thank for backtics / quote .. you are  right ..  anyway .. the way are essentially two . string concat on var with quote .. i have update the answer .. but  .. in SQL every aspect is good for an encyclopedia..

Comment: No problem, I just don't get how your answer is different from what the op seems to be trying already (the backticks) ^^

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i was so busy scratching my head about the backticks i just didn't think using the string concat.
Just a thing, @scaisEdge: the problem weren't the backticks in the query, but the quotes before and after the name in the database created.